# Printing specific date range in ms project 2016

Tags: ms-project, pm-software, scheduling, ms-project-2016

I am trying to print a specific date range from a gantt chart view in ms project 2016, but all that prints out is the whole project. Can you help?

Answer (score 1):

1. The Dates in print settings only affect the timescale.
2. Use the built-in "Date Range" filter (in the Data group of the View ribbon) to show only tasks that start or finish within a certain range.  (It's an interactive filter that will prompt you for the two dates.)  After applying the filter, try printing again.